# I have entered a word in character array and want to find out the length of the word

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    
    char arr[100]="apple";
    int i=0;
    
    while(arr[i]!='/0'){
        i++;
    }
    
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

After running it I didn't get output. What's the mistake?
I have just started C++.

Comment: replace `'/0'` with `'\0'`

Comment: Why are you not simply using `std::string` instead? `string s = “apple”; int i = s.size();` Or at least `std::strlen()`? `int i = strlen(arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null character is denoted by a backslash not a slash. I am guessing that in your case, you get an infinite loop. '/0' is a multicharacter literal while '\0' is the null character. In your case, the correct code will be the following :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    
    char arr[100]="apple";
    int i=0;
    
    while(arr[i]!='\0'){
        i++;
    }
    
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest using strlen instead as it is faster and simpler. Nevertheless, your method is good for beginners so that you have a sense of loopings. In addition, you can think of adopting the string library in C++.

Comment: `'/0'` is not two characters.   It is a multi-character literal.  Multi-character literals are conditionally supported by the implementation (aka compiler and library).  If supported, they have type `int`, and implementation-defined values.